# insert raw parens in scheme-mode

Tags: emacs, scheme, parentheses

What's the standard way of inserting raw left- and right- parens when scheme-mode is active? Is there a standard key binding?

My current method to insert only a left-paren is:

1. type `(` which inserts the pair: `()`
2. insert `;;` between the parens
3. delete the right paren and the semis

Update: It turns out that I have the Prelude (https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) installed in my .emacs.d directory, and this loads the `smartparens.el` library which is handling the `(` and `)` keys.

Comment: (untested) please try `C-q (` and `C-q )`. If it works, I'll add it as an answer :)

Comment: yes, it works! please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- For the opening bracket: `C-q (`
- For the closing bracket: `C-q )`

Answer (score 3):

Do you also *sometimes want* the bad behavior that you describe?  If not, just bind `(` and `)` to `self-insert-command` in `scheme-mode-map`.  That way you won't have to use `C-q` each time, to insert a paren.

Oh, but I see that parens should *already* self-insert in Scheme mode - so forget that.

So you must be doing something in addition, not just `scheme-mode`, to get the bad behavior you describe.

Try `C-h k (` to find out what command `(` is bound to. Then go looking for that command, to see what code you are loading that is making that key binding.  (You might be able to guess the library by the command name.)

If that doesn't help you find it, and you do want to find where that binding is made and remove/prevent it, then bisect your init file recursively (by commenting out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8...) until you find what is creating the key bindings that you do not like.

Comment: It calls `sp--self-insert-command` which is defined in `smartparens.el`. That command is a wrapper around `self-insert-command` which (I suppose) special cases pairs like parens, brackets and braces. I'll look in my .emacs.d directory to find how that is getting loaded.

Comment: Sounds like you simply want to turn off smart-parens mode (or whatever it's called) when in `scheme-mode`. You know how to do that, right?

Comment: yeah - I need to do that temporarily. Generally I like what smart-parens does, but sometimes I misjudge the boundaries of an s-exp and find that I need to insert a `)(` pair or I need to embed an s-exp inside a new `()` pair.

Comment: That's why I asked whether you *sometimes* ***do*** *want* the behavior that you asked about avoiding. There are several ways to go. You can have parens insert normally by default and insert pairwise via a special key, or vice versa. You can toggle any mode off/on with a key. Etc.